# JNA - Getting Base address

Tags: java, jna

Recently I have been working on a little project of mine, which is Memory reading/writing in java for native games (C/C++/etc).

At the moment I have a base where I can read and write to memory of games, but I now need a way to get the Base address of the running application. For example:

I have a list of pointers that I have collected using Cheat Engine and its Pointer searcher.
These are stable and work each time the game reloads.

The problem I am facing now, is the first pointer uses the base address of the program (which changes every time the program restarts):
"ac_client.exe"+000DF73C

I am in need of a way to get the base value of "ac_client.exe" using JNA.

I have done a lot of research and found a few ways to do it in C++, but my knowledge of C/C++ is pretty limited.. I am finding it difficult to convert it to Java using JNA and I thought I would ask here and see if anyone would be able to be of assistance or know of alternate ways of doing such a feat.

Thanks for any help in advance,
Kaden.

[EDIT]

Read my solution bellow! thanks for the help.

Comment: i've actually got my own project similar to yours for the same reason. JNA does not have its own built in implementation of `EnumProcessModules()` and it's lacking an implementation of `MODULEENTRY32` for the ToolHelp32Snapshot method of walking through the modules. I tried to get my own `EnumProcessModules` up and running from some code I found and google, but no luck. you can check out the code i was referencing here: https://code.google.com/p/dsexplorer/source/browse/trunk/DSexplorer/src/luz/memoryTool/interfaces/Psapi.java?r=8

Comment: @AlexLynch, That was perfect, I finally got it working. I will post the method I made, using a few of the classes from within that project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working after a bit of messing around with what Alex posted, and managed to get it working.

for anyone else who wanted to get something like this working, have a look at that project that Alex posted and you will see the required classes you will need. then I just used this:

```
public int getBaseAddress() {
        try {
                Pointer hProcess = gethProcess();
                List<Module> hModules = PsapiHandler.getInstance().EnumProcessModules(hProcess);

                for(Module m: hModules){
                        if(m.getFileName().contains(exeName)){
                                misc.log(m.getFileName() + ": 0x" + Long.toHexString(Pointer.nativeValue(m.getEntryPoint())));
                                return Integer.valueOf("" + Pointer.nativeValue(m.getLpBaseOfDll()));
                        }
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {  e.printStackTrace(); }
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: hah :D glad you got it working. I tried pretty much the same thing myself and it simply did not work. no error message or anything, just nothing. typical JNA. good job!

Comment: without the link you gave me I would have given up haha, I simply didn't have a clue how it was meant to be done. Thanks again @Alex

Comment: I am receiving an exception myself - `java.lang.Exception: EnumProcessModules failed. Error: 299 at com.haxx.PsapiTools.EnumProcessModules(PsapiTools.java:53)` - no idea what would cause this. did you run into this, or am i on my own? :)

Comment: "Error Code 299
System error code 299 means "Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed." This error code may also display as "ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY" or as the value 0x12B."  thats all I can come up with for that haha.. I never had any issues, it pretty much worked first time after I hacked together the classes a a bit. I remember I needed to make a few small changes to the classes, but that was all for compiling. I would need to see the code I think =P