# Java (JNA API) - Calculating Base Address

Tags: java, memory, jna

USING **JNA API** with Java, I've been searching through memory of a game, attempting to withdraw a multi-level pointer to a certain address in order to get around the DMA that is utilized. When I succeeded, the pointers address was based upon the *"gamename.exe"+0000025C* and several levels of offsets.

With this, and the base address of the gamename.exe being dynamically reset upon restart of the client, I will need to calculate the base address.

I am using Java and have found this StackOverflow post to be of great help setting up a method [JNA - Getting Base address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15954142/jna-getting-base-address/15962569#15962569)

I have written a similar method, snippet below:

```
public int getBaseAddress() {
    try {
            Pointer hProcess = main.Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetCurrentProcess();
            System.out.println(hProcess);
            
            List<Module> hModules =       PsapiTools.getInstance().EnumProcessModules(hProcess);
            System.out.println(hModules);
            
            for(Module m: hModules){
                System.out.println(m.getFileName());
                    if(m.getFileName().contains("NexusTK.exe")){
                            m.log(m.getFileName() + ": 0x" + Long.toHexString(Pointer.nativeValue(m.getEntryPoint())));
                            System.out.println(m);
                            return Integer.valueOf("" +    Pointer.nativeValue(m.getLpBaseOfDll()));
                    }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {  e.printStackTrace(); }
        return -1;
}
```

Full class found [here](http://pastebin.com/QMzVE7u3)

[This](http://pastebin.com/12XGuBmn) is what my console shows. Lots of DLL's but no .exe of my game.

**QUESTION:**

How do I find the process of my game client through the Module collection? Am I feeding the function the correct Pointer? Do I need to restructure the code to calculate the base address?

Comment: Edited. Thank you for pointing out the necessity for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are enumerating all the modules of the current process, that is: your process, that is: `javaw.exe`. That's because you feed the `EnumProcessModules` API with the result of `GetCurrentProcess()`

If you want to enumerate the modules of **another process**, you need to use `OpenProcess` with it's `PID`.

You can get a PID with two methods:

1. [Enumerating the processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684865.aspx).
2. [Finding some window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499.aspx), and [then its PID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I fed the function my readrights/processname from OpenProcess and got the results I was looking for. Your explanation was very much appreciated! (Though I feel a bit silly)

Comment: Cool. You should accept the answer, then. It will bring you a small reputation increase. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Oh that's how you do it. I wanted to upvote you like I'd do on reddit, but that required some rep.

Comment: @Syncretic Thanks. Enjoy your new reputation.