# Getting base address of dll of specific process using JNA

Tags: java, c++, winapi, java-native-interface, jna

***Updated***: See updates at the bot of the question

---

I would like to get base address of `game.dll` which is inside war3.exe process.
I'm trying to do it via **JNA** library version 5.9.0, but no success.

The issue I faced with: I can't get game.dll module from war3.exe process.
I tried to get it using:

```
int pid = getProcessId("Warcraft III");
openProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, pid);
WinDef.HMODULE hMod = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetModuleHandle("game.dll")
```

But the result of `hMod` is `null`.

Also I have tried to get all modules that war3.exe process has. As you may see it contains only 5 modules and it doesn't contain `game.dll`. But when I open war3.exe via Process Explorer I see definitely more than 5.

**Executed with Intellij Idea:**
[image]

**Taken from Process Explorer:**
[image: game.dll pic]

Please, share your opinion and ideas why I get only 5 modules from IDE.

Any advice on how to get the `game.dll` module and its base address via JNA would be appreciated.

---

***Updates***:
As per Remy's answer I have made one more try with `EnumProcessModules()`.
Here is my code snippet:

```
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Psapi;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HMODULE;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLE;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS;
import static handler.memory.MemoryHandler.openProcess;

public class MemoryHandler {
    static final User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
    static final Psapi psapi = Psapi.INSTANCE;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int pid = getProcessId("Warcraft III");
        HANDLE process = openProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, pid);

        HMODULE[] hMods = new HMODULE[1024];
        psapi.EnumProcessModules(process, hMods, hMods.length, new IntByReference(1024));

        List<HMODULE> hModList = Arrays.asList(hMods);
        hModList.forEach(hMod ->
                System.out.println(Pointer.nativeValue(hMod.getPointer())));
    }

    public static int getProcessId(String window) {
        IntByReference pid = new IntByReference(0);
        user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(user32.FindWindow(null, window), pid);

        return pid.getValue();
    }
}
```

**And here is the result:**
[image]

As far as I understand I have got some pointers. But how should I understand which one from them is related to `game.dll`? I was assuming that I should get somehow the list on modules where I could see their names and base addresses.

Also if I change `System.out.println(Pointer.nativeValue(hMod.getPointer())));` to `hModList.forEach(System.out::println);` I see the following pointers and a lot of nulls (about 1000).

[image]

Do these addresses contain the address of `game.dll`?

Comment: Did you not find it remarkable, that you never have to pass the process handle (which, also remarkably, you don't find a reason to keep around) into the call to `GetModuleHandle()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found solution, but not in Java or JNA.
I wrote this code using C++ and I will use it like dll in Java.

Here is my C++ code:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <psapi.h>
using namespace std;

DWORD_PTR GetProcessBaseAddress(DWORD processID)
{
    DWORD_PTR   baseAddress = 0;
    HANDLE      processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processID);
    HMODULE* moduleArray;
    LPBYTE      moduleArrayBytes;
    DWORD       bytesRequired;

    if (processHandle)
    {
        if (EnumProcessModules(processHandle, NULL, 0, &bytesRequired))
        {
            if (bytesRequired)
            {
                moduleArrayBytes = (LPBYTE)LocalAlloc(LPTR, bytesRequired);

                if (moduleArrayBytes)
                {
                    unsigned int moduleCount;

                    moduleCount = bytesRequired / sizeof(HMODULE);
                    moduleArray = (HMODULE*)moduleArrayBytes;

                    if (EnumProcessModules(processHandle, moduleArray, bytesRequired, &bytesRequired))
                    {
                        baseAddress = (DWORD_PTR)moduleArray[0];
                    }

                    LocalFree(moduleArrayBytes);
                }
            }
        }

        CloseHandle(processHandle);
    }

    return baseAddress;
}

DWORD GetProcessId(LPCTSTR ProcessName) // non-conflicting function name
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 pt;
    HANDLE hsnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    pt.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    if (Process32First(hsnap, &pt)) { // must call this first
        do {
            if (!lstrcmpi(pt.szExeFile, ProcessName)) {
                CloseHandle(hsnap);
                return pt.th32ProcessID;
            }
        } while (Process32Next(hsnap, &pt));
    }
    CloseHandle(hsnap); // close handle on failure
    return 0;
}

uintptr_t GetModuleBaseAddress(DWORD procId, const wchar_t* modName)
{
    uintptr_t modBaseAddr = 0;
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, procId);
    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MODULEENTRY32 modEntry;
        modEntry.dwSize = sizeof(modEntry);
        if (Module32First(hSnap, &modEntry))
        {
            do
            {
                if (!_wcsicmp(modEntry.szModule, modName))
                {
                    modBaseAddr = (uintptr_t)modEntry.modBaseAddr;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(hSnap, &modEntry));
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
    return modBaseAddr;
}

int main()
{
    DWORD pid = GetProcessId(TEXT("war3.exe"));
    cout << "Process ID of war3.exe: "<< pid << endl;

    DWORD_PTR war3_exe_base_addr = GetProcessBaseAddress(pid);
    cout <<"Base address of war3.exe: "<< war3_exe_base_addr << endl;

    uintptr_t gameDllBaseAddress = GetModuleBaseAddress(pid, TEXT("game.dll"));
    cout <<"Base address of game.dll: " << gameDllBaseAddress << endl;
}
```

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`GetModuleHandle()` looks in the calling process only.  Since `game.dll` is not loaded in your own process, `GetModuleHandle()` can't find it.

To look for a module loaded in another process, you need to use either:

- [`EnumProcessModules()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocessmodules)/[`EnumProcessModulesEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocessmodulesex), using [`GetModuleFileNameEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmodulefilenameexw) to get their file names. See [Enumerating All Modules for a Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-modules-for-a-process).
- [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE|TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot), using [`Module32First()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-module32firstw)/[`Module32Next()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-module32nextw) to enumerate the snapshot. See [Traversing the Module List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/traversing-the-module-list).

`Kernel32Utils.getModules()` uses `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE)`, so if your Java app is running as a 64bit app then it will enumerate only 64bit modules.  But `war3.exe` is running as a 32bit process in your screenshot, so if you use `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` in a 64bit process then you would need to use `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32` instead.

**UPDATE:**

As I mentioned above, if you go the `EnumProcessModules()` approach, you can use `GetModuleFileNameEx()` to determine the filename of each module. That way, you can find the module for `game.dll`.

More importantly:

- you are lacking needed error handling of each system call. Always test return values for failures.
- not an error per-se, but you really should not be requesting `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` rights with `openProcess()`.  Request only the rights you actually need, no more. In this case, use `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ` instead.
- you are not looking at the output of the 4th parameter of `EnumProcessModules()` to know how many modules were actually stored in the array.
- your input values of the 3rd and 4th parameters of `EnumProcessModules()` are wrong, they need to be expressed in *bytes*, not in *elements*.

Per the [`EnumProcessModules()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocessmodules):

> `cb`
> The size of the lphModule array, **in bytes**.
>
> `lpcbNeeded`
> The **number of bytes** required to store all module handles in the `lphModule` array.
>
> ...
>
> It is a good idea to specify a large array of HMODULE values, because it is hard to predict how many modules there will be in the process at the time you call `EnumProcessModules`. **To determine if the `lphModule` array is too small to hold all module handles for the process, compare the value returned in `lpcbNeeded` with the value specified in `cb`. If `lpcbNeeded` is greater than `cb`, increase the size of the array and call `EnumProcessModules` again**.
>
> **To determine how many modules were enumerated by the call to `EnumProcessModules`, divide the resulting value in the `lpcbNeeded` parameter by `sizeof(HMODULE)`**.

Comment: This seems to be a [common question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjna%5D+%22base+address%22&searchOn=3) and I'm surprised there's no canonical.  Do you think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920113/java-jna-api-calculating-base-address) would work?   Would you be willing to expand your answer here to make this the canonical?

Comment: I agree with Daniel. It would be greate to have actual example as I have looked at a lot of topics, but they are very old.

Comment: The question is updated, according to Remy's answer.

Comment: Thank you @RemyLebeau. You are right about 3rd and 4th params in documentation. But in jna-5.9.0 this method looks like: boolean EnumProcessModules(HANDLE hProcess, HMODULE[] lphModule, int cb, IntByReference lpcbNeeded);

Comment: @Neo That doesn't change what I said. You still have to pass in the proper values for `cb` and `lpcbNeeded`. 1024 is not the correct value for either parameter

Comment: @Remy Nothing happened. I got all modules via `EnumProcessModules()` but their count is 5 as on my first screenshot in the question and still no `game.dll` present here. Sad :(

Comment: @Neo are you SURE you are enumerating the modules of the correct process ID to begin with? Did you compare the process ID from `getProcessId()` with the one reported by Task Manager/Process Explorer? It is really hard to tell from your screenshots, since we can't see the other processes that are present.

Comment: Yes @RemyLebeau I compared them. They are the same. I just would like to get somehow baseAddress of this `game.dll` in memory, but still no success.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237108/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-neo).

Comment: @Remy I sent messages in chat, but you didn't answer.. Do you have a chance to take a look inside chat?

Comment: @Neo no, I hadn't looked yet, because I was never notified that there were new messages. I have posted some now...