# Java JNA getting baseaddress

Tags: java, memory, jna

How do I get first address of this "jvm.dll"+0001954C ?

I found article: [JNA - Getting Base address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15954142/jna-getting-base-address) but it's already outdated and 3 years old.

I need find what's the address of this basically "jvm.dll"+0001954C

Comment: How would you do it in C?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DFUyyUkb i tried and worked perfect

Comment: Please put the code directly into your question.  Don't use Java `long` unless you want a 64-bit value.