# Copying data from a DLL to a ByteBuffer (JNA)

Tags: java, dll, jna

I'm porting a Python script using ctypes over to Java.

Part of the script copies data from the DLL's virtual memory to a buffer, which stores said data to copy back later. I'm not sure how to accomplish this in JNA.

I do have exact values for the virtual addresses where the data I want is stored, but I'm not sure how to get a pointer to point at those virtual addresses, since JNA's Javadoc never specifies whether a pointer is relative to system memory or DLL memory.

How do I set a pointer to point at a specified (virtual) memory address from Java? In Python, the right value can be set using `dll._handle + address`.

Comment: Just a sidenote, but I noticed a certain private field `handle` exists in `NativeLibrary`. I'm not sure whether this is the address I'm after, but I think it is.

Comment: You can extract the `handle` value from the `toString()` of the library after you load it.

Comment: Will it point to the base address? I find this to be more convenient than going through the Windows APIs.

Comment: It will point to the base address of the DLL. I can't guarantee that it the DLL will be loaded into contiguous memory, however.  Use at your own risk!

Comment: It seems that when I set a pointer to point at the right address and try to write to it, JNA gives me an invalid memory access error. Is this just how JNA works?

Comment: Sort-of. That's actually part of JNI and is an error message protecting from a crash of the native app.  Otherwise you'd crash with a sigsegv.  For security reasons you can't just arbitrarily write to memory you don't own.    So... you probably need to use native API methods that give you authorized access to that memory and not just plain pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JNA's `Pointer` class indirects (global) system memory and is equivalent to C's `&foo` notation for pointing to the unique, global, systemwide memory address of `foo`.

The class ​has a [`Pointer(long peer)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmoduleinformation?redirectedfrom=MSDN) constructor which takes the actual native memory address as an argument.  (You can also extract this value using `Pointer.nativeValue()`.) This is not usually needed, as users should not normally have to worry about specific memory addresses.  As the Javadoc states:

> Don't use this unless you know what you're doing.

Beyond that, if you need a virtual address relative to some other base point, you need to find the appropriate platform-specific function which can identify that native pointer address for you.  For example, in Windows, you would use [`GetModuleInformation()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmoduleinformation?redirectedfrom=MSDN).  [This is mapped](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.8.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Psapi.html#GetModuleInformation-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLE-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HMODULE-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Psapi.MODULEINFO-int-) in the user-contributed JNA mappings (`jna-platform` artifact) in the `Psapi` interface, or you can map it yourself.  The [`MODULEINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/ns-psapi-moduleinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN) structure you get using that method will contain the starting address for the DLL, and you can add an offset, although it appears to be identical to the `HMODULE` input, so perhaps all you need to call is [`EnumProcessModules()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocessmodules?redirectedfrom=MSDN).  [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15962569/1161484) provides the code you need to do this (although I'd use `long` for 64-bit pointers).

Note the [cautions in the Javadoc](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.8.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Psapi.html#EnumProcessModules-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLE-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HMODULE:A-int-com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference-) for that in JNA's Psapi class:

> If the module list in the target process is corrupted or not yet initialized, or if the module list changes during the function call as a result of DLLs being loaded or unloaded, EnumProcessModules may fail or return incorrect information.

There are many more caveats there.

**Update:** per your comment, the `handle` of a loaded DLL is exposed in the library's `toString()`.  For example:

```java
Kernel32 foo = Kernel32.INSTANCE;
System.out.println(foo.toString());
```

will return

> Proxy interface to Native Library kernel32.dll@140737217757184

Again, "Don't use this unless you know what you're doing."